# ASP.NET MVC: Making an anonymous action secure without authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have the following two action methods in one of my controllers:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ViewResult> ClearAlerts(string userId)
{
   // Clear the alerts
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ViewResult> DenyAlerts(string userId)
{
   // Deny the alerts
}
```

Links to these two action methods are sent in an e-mail by my application to a single individual. `userId` is a GUID string generated by the Identity framework and is included as a query parameter in the two hyperlinks in the e-mail.

I'm concerned that these anonymous methods may be called by someone other than the individual who receives the e-mail.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Is there a way of making an anonymous action method accessible to only a single individual without requiring user authorization?
2. What is the likelihood that someone could 'guess' a valid `userId` call these methods with it?
3. Should I just bite the bullet and require authorization for these actions?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the individual have a login/credentials that you can associate with a token that is sent in the email instead? Kind of like how password resets work or something?

Comment: First of all if it's allow anonymous why userid is required if required so better to use authorization o just create interface which take some info from user or use generate guid on every hit.

Comment: @Nikki9696 I wanted to avoid giving the single individual login credentials because they are a non-technical person who is not a member of our department. I wanted to make it as easy as possible for them to clear alerts on our system and avoid the hassle of having them create an account on our system.

This individual's e-mail address is known to the application via a web.config file entry. I did toy with the idea of generating some sort of validation token (e.g. a SHA1 hash of the user's e-mail address). But I wasn't sure if that made any sense or would enhance security anyway.

Comment: Any solution that's coming to my mind involves more work for you than is likely warranted for something just to avoid giving the person an actual login and authenticating. I would say you're best off just giving him a login if that's the only reason for this, but that's just an opinion from someone who works mostly places that audit everything  =)

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unlikely that someone would guess a valid `userId`, I would not worry about that.

I'm guessing you're going to check for a valid user with `usermanager`. So if the user is not found, then that means that someone tried to access the action method "incorrectly". Just silently ignore and redirect to another page. Like so:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public async Task<ViewResult> ClearAlerts(string userId)
 {

      if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( userId ) )
      {
          return RedirectToAction( "Index","Home" );
      }

      var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync( userId );

      if( user == null )
      {
          return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
      }

      // do stuff
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have logic which checks if `userId` does actually represent a real user. The issue really is whether it is terribly likely that someone other than the e-mail recipient would access these action methods and update the alert status. Maybe it's not that high of a risk, since `userId` is a GUID which, as you mentioned, is highly unlikely of being guessed.